# OpenCV 2.4.6 crash at program runtime

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi

I have compiled OpenCV 2.4.6 on my Raspberry Pi using the Sourceforge repository. I used the following commands to install it:

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-unix/2.4.6/opencv-2.4.6.tar.gz
tar zxvf opencv-2.4.6.tar.gz  
cd opencv-2.4.6
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_gpu=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_ocl=OFF    
make install
```

I get no errors when I compile. I am using the Face Recognition API to recognize faces from video captured through the Raspberry Pi camera module. I am using a C++ API called RaspiCam to capture frames from the camera, and it is compatible with OpenCV, allowing you to save captured frames as an OpenCV Mat object. The documentation for the API is at http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/40. The source code for building the RaspiCam library is http://sourceforge.net/projects/raspicam/files/?source=navba.

Most of the time when I run my face recognition application, it runs fine. But every now and then, when I run my app it becomes unresponsive after an unpredictable amount of time with no error. Task Manager shows that the program is still running, but at a very small CPU usage like 2% instead of the usual 70-80% that it normally uses. I placed OpenCV try blocks for error handling to catch any OpenCV errors that may arrive, but none of them get invoked. I have noticed that my program crashes less often when I don't use the OpenCV highgui window to display frames, particularly if I run it through ssh. Has anyone had any similar problems?

Comment: I determined that my program crashes at raspicam's grab() function.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem with 'raspicam-0.1.1'. For me, downgrading the raspberry pi firmware resolved the problem.

```
sudo rpi-update 8660fe5152f6353dec61422808835dbcb49fc8b2
```

I found this firmware version mentioned when I was browsing the [RPi-Cam-Web-Interface](http://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface#Issues_with_latest_Camera_Firmware)

Comment: Interesting. I only tried upgrading the firmware. I ended up using the Python Raspberry Pi camera library called Picamera which gave no issues. Every now and then a bad frame was captured which triggered an exception when OpenCV processed the frame, but I was able to catch the exception and grab the next frame, preventing my program from crashing.